# Create random questions with random answer app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a quiz App with 10 randomly questions. The problem is, I can only shuffle the questions and can’t shuffle the correct answers. So no matter what the question is, the correct answers doesn’t change.

**index.html:** If the index of a selected question is equal to the index of the correctAnswer array, the result would be correct

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
                        <h2>Results:</h2>
                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                
                            <button class="btn"
                                ng-repeat="question in results.dataService.quizQuestions"
                                ng-class="{'btn-success': question.correct, 'btn-danger': !question.correct}"
                                ng-click="results.setActiveQuestion($index)">
                
                                    <span class="glyphicon"
                                        ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': question.correct, 'glyphicon-remove': !question.correct}"></span>
                                                 
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 top-buffer">
                                <h2>You scored {{results.quizMetrics.numCorrect}} / {{results.dataService.quizQuestions.length}}</h2>
                                <h2><strong>{{results.calculatePerc() | number:2 }}%</strong></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="row">
                            <h3>Questions:</h3>
                            <div class="col-12"></div>
                            <div class="well well-sm">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        
                                        <h4> {{results.activeQuestion + 1 + "." + results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].text}} </h4>
                                        <div class="row"
                                                 ng-if="results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].type === 'text'">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="answer in results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].possibilities">
                                                <h4 class="answer"
                                                        ng-class="results.getAnswerClass($index)">
                                                        {{answer.answer}}
                                                    <p class="pull-right" ng-show="$index !== results.quizMetrics.correctAnswers[results.activeQuestion] && $index === results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].selected">Your answer</p>
                                                    <p class="pull-right" ng-show="$index === results.quizMetrics.correctAnswers[results.activeQuestion]">Right answer</p>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

**dataservice.js:** is where the array of the questions and correctAnswers , and the questionRandomize function are stored

```
(function(){
    angular
    .module("quizApp")
    .factory("DataService", DataFactory);

    function DataFactory(){
        var dataObj = {
            quizQuestions: quizQuestions,
         correctAnswers: correctAnswers 
        };
        return dataObj;
        
    }

    var correctAnswers = [1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3]; 

    var quizQuestions  = [
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Mit was ist der Tennisball umgeben?",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "Mit einer Nylonummantelung"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Mit einer Schicht Eichhörnchenhaaren"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Mit einer Filzschicht"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Mit einer speziellen Gummischicht"
                    }
            ],
            
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Das flächenmäßig kleinste Bundesland heißt...",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "Berlin"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Hamburg"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "München"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Leipzig"
                    }
            ],
        
             selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Was ist die Goldener Himbeere?",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "ein Preis für die schlechteste Leistung innerhalb eines Filmjahres"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "eine Nachspeise aus Russland"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "das teuerste Schmuckstück der Welt"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "das Symbol einer Sekte"
                    }
            ],
            
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Welcher deutsche Herrscher trug den Beinamen der Große?",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "Friedrich der I. von Preußen"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Friedrich der III. von Sachsen"                            
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Friedrich II. von Preußen"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Friedrich der III. von Österreich"
                    }
            ],
            
     selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Welcher Pilz ist einer der giftigsten der Welt?",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "der Grüne Knollenblätterpilz"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "der Gemeine Kartoffelbovist"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "der Fliegenpilz"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "der Satansröhrling"
                    }
            ],
            
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Welche Gürtelfarbe existiert nicht im Kampfsport Karate?",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "schwarz"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "weiß"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Rot"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "blau"
                    }
            ],
            
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Welche Insel gehört nicht zu den Balearischen Inseln?",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "Ibiza"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Cabrera"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Formentera"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Gran Canaria"
                    }
            ],
            
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Welcher Schauspieler hat nicht in einem James Bond-Film mitgespielt?",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "Timothy Dalton"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Daniel Craig"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Leonardo DiCaprio"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Javier Bardem"
                    }
            ],
        
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Farbe von einem Baum?",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "lila"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "grün"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "rosa"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "grau"
                    }
            ],
        
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Einen Feinschmecker nennt man auch ...",
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "Gourmet."
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Genießer."
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Gourmed."
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Leckermäulchen."
                    }
            ],
            
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        }
    ];
    quizQuestions = randomize(quizQuestions);

    function randomize (quizQuestions) {
        var index;
        var temp;
        for (var i = quizQuestions.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                //get random number
                index = Math.floor((Math.random() * i));
                //swapping
                temp = quizQuestions[index];
                quizQuestions[index] = quizQuestions[i];
                quizQuestions[i] = temp; 
        }
//edit to pass the obj back to the function
        return quizQuestions; 

}

})();
```

**quizMetrics.js:** The markQuiz function marks if the answers are correct or not

```
(function () {
  angular.module("quizApp").factory("quizMetrics", QuizMetrics);

  QuizMetrics.$inject = ["DataService"];

  function QuizMetrics(DataService) {
    var quizObj = {
      correctAnswers: [],
      markQuiz: markQuiz,
      numCorrect: 0,
    };
    return quizObj;

    function markQuiz() {
      quizObj.correctAnswers = DataService.correctAnswers;
      for (var i = 0; i < DataService.quizQuestions.length; i++) {
        if (
          DataService.quizQuestions[i].selected ===
          DataService.correctAnswers[i]
        ) {
          DataService.quizQuestions[i].correct = true;
          quizObj.numCorrect++;
        } else {
          DataService.quizQuestions[i].correct = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

**quiz.js:**

```
(function () {
  angular.module("quizApp").controller("quizCtrl", QuizController);

  QuizController.$inject = ["quizMetrics", "DataService"];

  function QuizController(quizMetrics, DataService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.quizMetrics = quizMetrics;
    vm.dataService = DataService;
    vm.questionAnswered = questionAnswered;
    vm.setActiveQuestion = setActiveQuestion;
        vm.selectAnswer = selectAnswer;
        vm.finaliseAnswers = finaliseAnswers;
    vm.activeQuestion = 0;
    vm.error = false;
    vm.finalise = false;

    var numQuestionsAnswered = 0;
        
        
    function setActiveQuestion(index) {             
      if (index === undefined) {
        var breakOut = false;
        var quizLength = DataService.quizQuestions.length - 1;

        while (!breakOut) {
          vm.activeQuestion =
            vm.activeQuestion < quizLength ? ++vm.activeQuestion : 0;

          if (vm.activeQuestion === 0) {
            vm.error = true;
          }

          if (DataService.quizQuestions[vm.activeQuestion].selected === null) {
            breakOut = true;
          }
        }
      } else {
        vm.activeQuestion = index;
      }
        }
        

    function questionAnswered() {
      var quizLength = DataService.quizQuestions.length;

      if (DataService.quizQuestions[vm.activeQuestion].selected !== null) {
        numQuestionsAnswered++;
        if (numQuestionsAnswered >= quizLength) {
          for (var i = 0; i < quizLength; i++) {
            if (DataService.quizQuestions[i].selected === null) {
              setActiveQuestion(i);
              return;
            }
          }
          vm.error = false;
          vm.finalise = true;
          return;
        }
      }

      vm.setActiveQuestion();
    }

    function selectAnswer(index) {
      DataService.quizQuestions[vm.activeQuestion].selected = index;
        }
        
        function finaliseAnswers(){
            vm.finalise = false;
            numQuestionsAnswered = 0;
            vm.activeQuestion = 0;
            quizMetrics.markQuiz();
            quizMetrics.changeState("quiz", false);
            quizMetrics.changeState("results", true);
        }
  }
})();
```

**results.js:**

```
(function(){

  angular
    .module("quizApp")
    .controller("resultsCtrl", ResultsController);

    ResultsController.$inject = ['quizMetrics', 'DataService'];

  function ResultsController(quizMetrics, DataService){
        var vm = this;
        
        vm.quizMetrics = quizMetrics;
        vm.dataService = DataService;
        vm.getAnswerClass = getAnswerClass;
        vm.setActiveQuestion = setActiveQuestion;
        vm.reset = reset;
        vm.calculatePerc = calculatePerc;
        vm.activeQuestion = 0;

        function calculatePerc(){
            return quizMetrics.numCorrect / DataService.quizQuestions.length * 100;
        }

        function setActiveQuestion(index){
            vm.activeQuestion = index;
        }

        function getAnswerClass(index){
            answer.selected = true;
            if(index === quizMetrics.correctAnswers[vm.activeQuestion]){
                return "bg-success";
            }else if(index === DataService.quizQuestions[vm.activeQuestion].selected){
                return "bg-danger";
            }
        }

        function reset(){

            quizMetrics.changeState("results", false);
            quizMetrics.numCorrect = 0;
        
            for(var i = 0; i < DataService.quizQuestions.length; i++){
                var data = DataService.quizQuestions[i]; //binding the current question to data to keep code clean
        
                data.selected = null;
                data.correct = null;
            }
        }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question more - 'I have tried to create a function of random questions but the correct answers were stable. It doesn't go with the questions.'

Comment: I want to create a quiz App with 10 randomly questions. The problem is, I can only shuffle the questions and can’t shuffle the correct answers. So no matter what the question is, the correct answers doesn’t change.

Comment: so once you get the question, you want to shuffle the order of the answers- eg- orginal order - ABCD can change to ACBD or DCBA etc

Comment: Yes that’s what I mean

Comment: check the answer below, if you still cannot get the desired result, let me know for the complete solution.

Comment: I can shuffle the questions and the answers as bellow, but the correct answers of my app  are store in a seperated arrays from the questions ( ikl answer) array. So if I shuffle the correct answer, it doesn't make sense. I have tried to store each correct answer in the question object instead of in a separate array and change "correctAnswer" array to "quizQuestions[vm.activeQuestion].answer". But it gives error : answer is not defined. ("answer" is the correct answer in the quizQuestions object).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to store each correct answer in the question object instead of in a separate array:

```
var quizQuestions  = [
        {
            type: "text",
            text: "Mit was ist der Tennisball umgeben?",
            answer: 3,
            possibilities: [
                    {
                            answer: "Mit einer Nylonummantelung"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Mit einer Schicht Eichhörnchenhaaren"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Mit einer Filzschicht"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "Mit einer speziellen Gummischicht"
                    }
            ],
            
            selected: null,
            correct: null 
        },
```

and then after you shuffle the array, the answer is still with the correct object.

Comment: I have set  "answer:3" to all the questions in the quizQuestions object and replace "correctAnswers" in index.html, results.js and quizMetrics.js  with "quizQuestion[vm.activeQuestion].answer" but it gives error: "answer is not defined". I defined it as a Number but it still didn't work. :((

Answer (score 0):

So in the method you get your randomised question, pass in the the answers again to shuffle it.

```
function shuffle(arra1) {
    var ctr = arra1.length, temp, index;

// While there are elements in the array
    while (ctr > 0) {
// Pick a random index
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
// Decrease ctr by 1
        ctr--;
// And swap the last element with it
        temp = arra1[ctr];
        arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
        arra1[index] = temp;
    }
    return arra1;
}
var myArray = [     {
                            answer: "A"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "B"                            
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "C"
                    },
                    {
                            answer: "D"
                    }
];
console.log(shuffle(myArray));
```

[Reference](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-array-exercise-17.php)- Check the live demo here